# Making a transparent tab background?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs, transparent, tabpage

I was wondering if I could draw the background of a tabpage in C# transparent like so I can see behind the window itself. I though it would give a cool effect but I don't know if or how I can do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the **Appearance** property of TabControl to **Buttons** Instead of using BackColor property. That would bring transparent tab page look and cool effect.

Answer (score 1):

VB & C# syntax

```
TabPage1.BackColor = Color.Transparent
```

this will show the tabpage1 color as the form color.

Comment: Set the form's BackgroundImage property to see that this doesn't actually work.